# How to execute two effects and get their respective return values (which maybe a success or an error)

Tags: scala, zio

I try to parallelize this sequential and fail fast solution:

```
 for
      cellTowersPayload <- CellHintTransformer.createGoogleApiPayload(cellAndWifiHints.cellHints).mapError(mapRequirementsFailure)
      googleMapsResultCellTowers <- googleMapsApi.call(cellTowersPayload)
      wifiHintsPayload <- WlanHintTransformer.createGoogleApiPayload(cellAndWifiHints.wifiHints).mapError(mapRequirementsFailure)
      googleMapsResultWifiHints <- googleMapsApi.call(wifiHintsPayload) // TODO paralleize with call cell towers
      mappedResult <- mapResult(googleMapsResultCellTowers, googleMapsResultWifiHints)
    yield mappedResult
```

The resulting solution should make the 2 calls in parallel and return both results (which may be success or failure each). So no
fail fast if one of the calls fails

How do I do this idiomatic in ZIO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, there are two things here. You can do operations in parallel by using `.fork` on the ZIO you want to parallelize and then do the join on those forked fibers.

The problem is that You need to somehow make sure both of them are executed even if the other fails, ZIO by default will cancel another fiber if one of fibers fails to minimize computations. We can use something like `.either` to make sure that ZIO neve fails but instead returns `Either[E, A]`.

So, we would do something like:

```
for {
  zio1 <- firstOperation().fork().either
  zio2 <- secondOperation().fork().either
  result <- zio1.zip(zio2)
  tupleResult <- result.join
} yield tupleResult
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, looks good. 
I also got this hint: left.exit.zipPar(right.exit)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I just found out that the ".exit" suggested by Adam is too much, you also get an optional exception inside the cause in addition to the ZIO failure type.

Using "either" as you suggested drove me into the right direction. I use now:  left.either.zipPar(right.either)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Answered here https://discord.com/channels/629491597070827530/630498701860929559/1027300896599724102 by Adam Fraser

```
 left.exit.zipPar(right.exit)
```

Update, see comments why under Dominiks answer:

```
left.either.zipPar(right.either)
```